# How to check whether a subset of R^2 is a smooth curve

Tags: differential-geometry, real-analysis, algebraic-curves

Is there any useful lemma for me know whether a subset of R^2 is a smooth curve.
Is $S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:|x|^8+|y|^8=1\}$ a smooth curve? 
What about $T=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:|x|^{\frac{1}{2}}+|y|^{\frac{1}{2}}=1\}$?Is there a general method to check?

Comment: The preimage of a [regular value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Submersion_(mathematics)) under a smooth map is a smooth manifold.

Comment: Must smooth manifold a smooth curve? Can you give some hint?

Comment: Maybe you can briefly tell me what your definition of a smooth curve is?

Comment: Manifolds with dimension greater than $1$ won't be curves. (There are complex curves which are two dimensional real manifolds and not every two dimensional real manifold is a complex curve.)

Comment: I think that $f\in C^{\infty }([a,b ],R^2)$ is the definition of a smooth curve. Is it generally accepted?

Comment: I guess you want $(a,b)$? A smooth curve then can have self-intersections (also cusps, if you have no restrictions on the derivative, so I think you should say $f'(t)\ne 0$), so it does not need to be a manifold. On the other hand you can show that a connected manifold is either homeomorphic to $S^1$ or $(0,1)$ and then try to make this it smooth.

Comment: How about this definition <a  href=http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SmoothCurve.html> In its definition ,we don't need$f'(t)\ne 0$

Comment: I got it. S and T are 1-dim manifold. Solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are considering curves $f(x,y)=C$. By the implicit function theorem, you can find a smooth patch of the curve around any point where the gradient of the equation exists and is different from the zero vector.

For $f(x,y)=x^8+y^8=1$ the gradient is $(8x^7,8y^7)$ which is zero in both components only at the origin, which is not on the curve.

For $f(x,y)=\sqrt{|x|}+\sqrt{|y|}=1$ the gradient is not defined at points $(x,y)=(\pm1,0)$ and $(0,\pm1)$. Inspection shows that you get cusps at these points, which are not parts of a smooth curve.

Comment: We can say that $\nabla f $ does not equal to zero implies local parameterization. But a  graph can be locally parameterized  does not imply$\nabla f=0$.

Comment: Yes, that is why you have to investigate those situations using other methods. The ImpFT removes all the "boring" situations from consideration. As these form the general case for any sensibly definable $f$, one can afford to pay special attention to the singular cases.

Comment: But how can we continue local parameterization to a global function?